# font-awesome icon not displaying inside the textarea

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms, textarea, font-awesome

I am using bootstrap form, in which I have to display the font-awesome icon in the corner(end) of the textarea field. But, I couldn't display it inside that field. Instead, I am getting the `<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>` as the text inside that field.

Code:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-wnAC7ln+XN0UKdcPvJvtqIH3jOjs9pnKnq9qX68ImXvOGz2JuFoEiCjT8jyZQX2z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/regular.css" integrity="sha384-zkhEzh7td0PG30vxQk1D9liRKeizzot4eqkJ8gB3/I+mZ1rjgQk+BSt2F6rT2c+I" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-HbmWTHay9psM8qyzEKPc8odH4DsOuzdejtnr+OFtDmOcIVnhgReQ4GZBH7uwcjf6" crossorigin="anonymous">



<body>

        <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="textarea0">Question</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea0" rows="2">
                                        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                                </textarea>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.text-box {
  min-width: 480px;
}

.text-container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
.text-container .text-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.text-container textarea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
  background: none;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/solid.css" integrity="sha384-wnAC7ln+XN0UKdcPvJvtqIH3jOjs9pnKnq9qX68ImXvOGz2JuFoEiCjT8jyZQX2z" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/regular.css" integrity="sha384-zkhEzh7td0PG30vxQk1D9liRKeizzot4eqkJ8gB3/I+mZ1rjgQk+BSt2F6rT2c+I" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/fontawesome.css" integrity="sha384-HbmWTHay9psM8qyzEKPc8odH4DsOuzdejtnr+OFtDmOcIVnhgReQ4GZBH7uwcjf6" crossorigin="anonymous">



<body>

        <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="textarea0">Question</label>
                        <div class="text-box">
  <div class="text-container">
    <span class="text-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
    </span>
    <textarea  class="form-control" id="textarea0" rows="2">This is the text</textarea>
  </div>
</div>
                                
                                
                               
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```